# Getting Error on di:compile in Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.4.2, setup-di-compile

I have installed Magento 2.4.2 and then installed Claue Theme after setup theme and running command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

it will working on 5 from 9 then give an error like

```
Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 40 secs 286.0 MiB
In ClassReader.php line 45:
                                                                                                                                          
** **Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #3 [ <required> 
Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface $stockResolver ]  
of Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Fulltext\Datasource\InventoryData class                                   
                                                                                                                                          

In ClassReader.php line 34:
                                                                         
 Class Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface does not exist
```

I have check in app/config.php

there are 3 modules with name Smile

```
'Smile_ElasticsuiteCore' => 1,
    'Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog' => 1,
    'Smile_ElasticsuiteSwatches' => 1
```

I think that is causing the issue but don't know yet.

[image]

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Check in your composer.json that you are using the correct version of Smile ElasticSuite. For Magento 2.4.2 it should be smile/elasticsuite ~2.10.0

Comment: There is no package in my composer.json file with the same name when i installed it with composer require smile/elasticsuite ~2.10.0 it shows me that error i have upload a screenshot in my question.

Comment: @Prits refer this - https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite#%EF%B8%8F-magento-versions-compatibility-

Comment: Thanks for the LInk @sandip yes i have followed that link and tried to install like that it gave me that error which i have added in screenshot will you please check.

Comment: How did you install Magento? If you installed it using composer, you should have the magento/module-inventory-sales-api package installed. If your magento modules are int eh app directory, you might have to reinstall Magento using composer

Answer (score 0):

Yes there was an issue with my Magneto 2 Setup so i have again install it using composer and the problem is resolved and everything works fine.